# Java API for source formatting

Tags: java, syntax-highlighting, code-formatting

There are several PHP or js code formatting libs out there -- does anyone know if similar libs exist in Java?

Ie., Given a string of code, return a formatted string with syntax colouring etc.

It'd be ideal if it auto detected the language, but I might be pushing my luck there...

The text will ultimately be displayed within a Flex application, so while I *could* use a js lib, we'll be parsing large files (up to 6000 lines), so I'd like to keep client side processing minimal.

Ideal output is HTML without CSS, although I'll take what I can get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That are two distinct tasks. With regard to code formatting, look around using the keyword ["java beautifier"](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+beautifier). Here is a [list](http://java-source.net/open-source/code-beautifiers). I myself have had good experiences with [Jalopy](http://jalopy.sourceforge.net/) which also ships with an Eclipse plugin. With regard to syntax highlighting, it depends on where you'd like to use it. If programmatically, use [JHighlight](https://jhighlight.dev.java.net/), or if on a webpage, use [Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) (Stackoverflow also uses it and it can detect languages), or as an Eclipse export plugin, use [Java2HTML](http://www.java2html.de/).

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for the info. How can I use java2Html in my own java program. So that which ever java source file I give to it and it produces the formatted HTML ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try to see the Colorer Project: http://colorer.sourceforge.net/