# Standalone Java API for Code formatting

Tags: java, formatting, code-formatting

I am trying Eclipse code formatted Jar file for formatting Java and groovy code but it wont work any one know ant other open source Standalone Java API to format java code.
I followed [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585446/java-api-for-source-formatting) question but look like these API very old may be it will not work with Latest Java8 or Java7. Any other open source API? I have to use that API from my web application if it can format CSS,HTML,XML,CSS,Groovy it will great help to me.

Comment: what type of formatting your are talking about

Comment: Formatting like Eclipse do when someone press CTRL+SHIFT+F it format the code i want to do same thing